# How to assign a new value to a variable in Z3?

Tags: python, z3, smt, z3py

I have a variable `x` inside the SMT-Z3-Python-Solver and already assigned to it the value `23`.
How is it possible to reassign the value of `x` to e.g. `42`?
I am looking for a function like `s.reassign(x == 42)`.

```
# coding=utf-8
from z3 import *

x = Int('x')
s = Solver()

s.add(x == 36)
s.reassign(x == 42) # <- PseudoCode

if s.check() == sat:
    print s.model()[x]
else:
    print "UNSAT"
```

Comment: I believe that `s.add(x==36)` adds the _condition_ that `x` must equal 36, but it doesn't assign a value to `x`. Why do you want the same variable to take on a new value?

Comment: @Fons I have to program a solver which checks if the "Knight's tour" on a 4x4 and on a 5x5 field is possible. For that i have a current position `x` of  the knight and some movement constrained-rules, where the next possible moves are stored in a variable `y`. If the solver finds a possible `y`, `x` becomes `y` and the solver has to search for a new `y`. So the above code is just a small snippet of the whole...

Comment: Aha. I think that variables need to be constant in Z3. For example, you could write `x1` for the first position, `x2` for the second, etc. Or maybe you could use recursion?

Comment: Yes, `==` is not an assignment, but a constraint. If you need to analyse multiple `==`, you need to have multiple variables or use `push`/`pop` to add/remove constraints.

Comment: I see, thanks for the hint!

Comment: Did you look at the Knight's tour in https://yurichev.com/writings/SAT_SMT_by_example.pdf section 22.4? Dennis Yurichev also links to an interesting Hamiltonian path implementation in z3py [https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/examples/python/hamiltonian/hamiltonian.py]